# Word for displaying the percentage of works hours logged by employee

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

In a project we need to display percentage of work done by the employee. For example in a week of 40 hrs, employee only logged in 20 hrs of work. Then we need to display 50%. That percentage can be either due to employee not completing the task or no task assigned. Can you please suggest a suitable word for this.

Comment: You mean employee  utilisation? http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/employee-utilization.html

Comment: Yes, similar to employee utilisation.

Answer (score 1):

- "On-task hours" - The employee's time may be spent outside the system.
- "Work hours" - As far as the system is concerned, it is work hours.
- simply: "Hours" - Best not to quibble over details when it comes to systems, let the person analysing the stats do that!

Answer (score 1):

The employee was [unutilized](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unutilized). It means not used or not used effectively.

Or

The employee was [mismanaged](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/mismanage?q=mismanaged). It means to manage badly or wrongly.

The first word doesn't assign blame but the second reeks of the fact that someone was responsible for this bad management.

Answer (score 0):

I work in an Agile Lifecycle Management of a Project. We define every individual's man-hours as their `CAPACITY`. If an employee can give 50% of his time and is on a leave for one day,

> we say his **capacity** is 50% of (40 - 8) = 16 hours

So I believe the word you are looking for is `CAPACITY`